Hint to prove Gagliardo Nirenberg Sobolev inequality
I'm working in the Gagliardo Nirenberg Sobolev inequality. My professor suggested to prove the following inequality.

For $N\geq 2$ integer and for all $t\geq 1$,
$$
   \|u\|^t_{L^{t\frac{N}{N-1}}(\mathbb{R}^N)}\leq t \|u\|^{t-1}_{L^{(t-1)\frac{N}{N-1}}(\mathbb{R}^N)}\prod_{i=1}^N\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right\|^{\frac{1}{N}}_{L^N(\mathbb{R}^N)}\quad \forall u\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R^N}).
$$

First, I thought that I can deduce this using Lemma 9.4 from Brezis Functional Analysis and PDE:

Let $N\geq 2$ and let $f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_N\in L^{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $1\leq i \leq N$ set
$$
    \tilde{x}_i = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_N)\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1},
$$
i.e., $x_i$ is omitted from the list. Then the function
$$
   f(x) = f_1(\tilde{x}_1)f_2(\tilde{x}_2)\cdots f_N(\tilde{x}_N),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^N,
$$
belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and
$$
   \|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}\leq \prod_{i=1}^N \|f_i\|_{L^{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})}.
$$

The idea is similar to deduce Sobolev, Gagliardo, Nirenberg inequality. Two cases, for the first: from first FTC
$$
u(x_1,\ldots,x_N)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_i} \partial u_i(x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},t,x_{i+1},\ldots, x_N)\, dt
$$
Then, in Lemma 9.4 with $f(x)=|u(x)|^{\frac{N}{N-1}}$ and
$$
   f_i(\tilde{x}_i) = \left| \int_{-\infty}^{x_i} \partial u_i(x_1,\ldots, x_{i-1},t,x_{i+1},\ldots, x_N)\, dt \right|
$$
we have that
$$
   \|u\|_{L^\frac{N}{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq \prod_{j=1}^{N} \left\|\partial_j u\right\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)}^{\frac{1}{N}}.
$$
But the last, term is in $L^1$ norm and I need in $L^N$ norm. I tried to modify the proof to my aim but I can't get anything.
Any idea or suggestion to this problem?

This is the first step. Now you should apply this inequality to $u^t$.

@daw I'm not sure how to get $N$ with your suggestion.

Your inequality holds also for all $u \in C_c^1(\mathbb R^N)$.
Take $u\in C_c^1(\mathbb R^N)$ and $t>1$. Then also $|u|^t \in C_c^1(\mathbb R^N)$. Applying your first inequality to $|u|^t$ yields
$$
\| \ |u|^t \ \|_{L^{ N/(N-1)}} \le \prod_j \| \frac\partial{\partial x_j} |u|^t\ \|_{L^1}^{1/N}.
$$
Now
$$
\| \ |u|^t \ \|_{L^{ N/(N-1)}} =(\int |u|^{ t N/(N-1)} dx)^{ (N-1)/N}
= \|u\|_{ L^{ tN/(N-1)}}^t,
$$
and
$$
\| \frac\partial{\partial x_j} |u|^t\ \|_{L^1}
\le t \cdot\| \ |u|^{t-1} \frac\partial{\partial x_j} u \ \|_{L^1}
\le t \|\frac\partial{\partial x_j} u \ \|_{L^N} \|\ |u|^{t-1}\|_{L^{N/(N-1)}}
= t \|\frac\partial{\partial x_j} u \ \|_{L^N} \| u\|_{L^{(t-1)N/(N-1)}}^{t-1}.
$$
Multiplying everything should prove the claim for $t>1$.

How to proceed in case $t=1$?

It's possible to take $u^t\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and conclude the same result? Why you need to use $|u|^t$?

The estimate is wrong for $u\in C^1(\mathbb R^n)$: take $u\equiv 1$. And $u^t$ might not be defined for $u<0$.

The claim makes no sense for $t=1$: what is $|u|^0_{L^0(\mathbb R^N)}$?

Sorry, I was thinking in $u^t\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^N)$ to avoid the derivate of absolute value.
